# angularjs change scope variable in my directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

this is my simple directive write in angularjs. My directive is simple to $http get value and set variable. When I run this directive I have a $digest error. Why? I use Angularjs 1.2.13.

my code:

```js
link77.directive('dbLabel', ['$http', 'remoteconf', function ($http, remoteconf) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    require: 'ngModel',
    replace: true,
    template: '<legend>{{valdb}}</legend>',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      
      var table = attrs.dbTable;
      var field   = attrs.dbField;
      var where   = attrs.dbWhere;
      
      scope.$apply(function () {
              $http({ 
                method: 'POST', 
                url: remoteconf.init.appApiEntryPoint + attrs.ngModulo + '/api/service.php?x=getdbval', 
                data: { 
                  xtable: table,
                  xfield: field,
                  xwhere: where
                } 
              }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                scope.valdb =  data.status;
                });
            });
        }

    }

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular.min.js"></script>

<db-label db-table="users" db-field="lastname" db-where="where id = {{user.id}}"/>
```

Comment: dont use scope.$apply, angular is in some $$phase already. and $http is used improperly even though your code never reach it.

Comment: How to correct my code? Sorry but i'm newbies...

Comment: there are a bunch of errors in your code, start with something simple. watch this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfnq449v/2/) and step by step add the content. Run frequently your code and check js errors with browser devtools. and take a look to angular [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)